# Can't get UIAlertView to work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview

I have a problem with UIAlertView i do not understand. I cannot get it to work. I have changed the code during test so the UIAlertView should hit directly when pressing the button.

I have tested with breakpoint/debugger and what is happening when i press the button is that the first line that it stops at is "otherButtonTitles:nil];".

I did test the piece of code in an other part of the app and it worked.

I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

```
- (IBAction)startNewGame_Button:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView *noPlayersAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"VARNING"
                                                             message:@"Ingen spelare är vald!\n \n Välj spelare och försök igen!" 
                                                            delegate:nil 
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [noPlayersAlert show];
    [noPlayersAlert release];

    ...
}
```

==============UPDATE=====================

When i copy this code to another button it works??

Here it is in one line, tested that with the same result:

```
UIAlertView *noPlayersAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"VARNING" message:@"Ingen spelare är vald!\n \n Välj spelare och försök igen!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

==============UPDATE #2==================

Problem solved, even if i do not understand the reason, as i removed an "exit(0)" i had far below the UIAlertView during the testing.

Thanks to all of you who answered :)

Comment: Set delegate self. error shows you the whole line of incorrect code. you can write the code above (uialertview implementation)in one line

Answer (score 0):

Why have you not set the delegate to self?

How do you know the line stops at `otherButtonTitles:nil`? If there is a crash log, post the results of it.

Comment: I did test with a breakpoint and stepped each line so i saw where it jumped.

Comment: Let the code run through and see what the crash log says, or post what you have as a report.

Comment: WrightsCS, you don't need the delegate unless you want to respond to interaction, and otherButtonTitles can be nil too. Like you said - we're going need a crash log to go anywhere with this.

Comment: the problem i have is that the program do not crash??

Comment: what is your problem then? Does the UIAlertView dismiss? If not, set delegate:self, simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

You must set delegate a value, because it needs to call `dissWith`, delegate method of the `alertView`. So please set:

```
delegate: self
```

Comment: It's iPhone so, expect the unexpected, Build -> Clean then Build -> Clean All targets then check if Why it's not working on where currently working so, so simple set delegate other than nil